# Round down whole number to value

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a C# function which rounds down whole positive or negative numbers to ten. For example: 19 -> 10; 11 -> 10; 99 -> 90; -11 -> -20; -19 -> -20.
Code:

```
public int RoundDownTo10(int value)
{
    if ((value < 0) && ((value % 10.0) != 0))
    {
        return (((int)Math.Truncate(value / 10.0)) - 1) * 10;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((int)Math.Truncate(value / 10.0)) * 10;
    }
}
```

I need help to make a function which can round down to any number given in the parameter list. For example: 
`RoundDownToNumber(int value, int roundDownToNumber) {...}`.

```
RoundDownToNumber(50, 30) -> 30;
RoundDownToNumber(20, 30) -> 0; 
RoundDownToNumber(-1, 30) -> -30; 
RoundDownToNumber(-51, 50) -> -100; 
RoundDownToNumber(149, 50) -> 100;
```

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly you want? your requirement doesn't matches with the method given in second code

Comment: Can't you simply subtract `value % 10` for positive `value`s, and `value % 10 + 10` for negative `value`s?

Comment: You round down to 10 with a code that use the value `10.0` and `10` four times... Haven't you tried anything ?

Comment: tel me what you want when what is entered. be specific.

Comment: no need to use floating point here

Comment: Miklós, there are several correct solutions. Why don't you accept one of them as the correct answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static int RoundDownToNumber(int value, int modulus)
{
    if (value < 0)
        return modulus*((value-modulus+1)/modulus);
    else
        return modulus*(value/modulus);
}
```

This gives the required output for all your example inputs.

Comment: Nice one. Please check my one-liner as well.

Answer (score 3):

The `% 10` operator will split off the last digit and its sign, so to speak: `34 % 10 == 4` and `-34 % 10 == -4`. For a **positive number** like `34`, we want to go from `34` to `30`, so we subtract the last digit from it:

```
if (value >= 0)
    return value - value % 10;
```

For a **negative number** like `-34`, we want to go to `-40`. We can subtract the `-4` that modulo gives us to reach `-30`, and then subtract `10` more, to reach `-40`:

```
else
    return value - value % 10 - 10;
```

Now replace the `10` with a variable, and you're done.

Comment: That is the way to do it. No floating point value with precision issue. No expensive division/multiplication with uncertainty result.

Comment: @Orace Do you think the '%' operator works without a division in its implementation?

Comment: Well, it works without a *floating point* division, which is what I think @Orace is worried about.

Comment: This code gives the wrong answer for negative inputs BTW.

Comment: Perhaps there should have been `return value - value % 10 - 10;`

Answer (score 1):

You already made whole work, just switch 10 to roundDownToNumber:

```
    public int RoundDownToNumber(int value, int roundDownToNumber)
    {
        if ((value < 0) && ((value % roundDownToNumber) != 0))
        {
            return (((int)Math.Truncate((double)value / roundDownToNumber)) - 1) * roundDownToNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((int)Math.Truncate((double)value / roundDownToNumber)) * roundDownToNumber;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int RoundDownToNumber(int value, int roundToNumber) {
    return value - ((roundToNumber + (value % roundToNumber)) % roundToNumber);
}
```

Explanation: We have to subtract the unnecessary surplus from value. So we have to determine the amount of unnecessary surplus. To not have to handle separate cases, we add `roundToNumber` to the modulo, making sure that we get a positive value and then we modulo again, making sure we get the exact needed value. This is a one-liner, formula-like solution.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
public int RoundDownToValue(int value,int RoundTo)
{
 if(value!=0 && RoundTo !=0)
  {
   int x = (((int)(value / RoundTo)));
   if ((value > 0))
   {       
    return (x*RoundTo);
   }
   else
   {
    return (x*RoundTo)+(RoundTo*(-1));
   }    
 }
}
```